# How to get all outfits for different companions

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Now that equipment is just decorative for companions (I approve personally) is there any way to get the various outfits that were handed out as quest rewards? Maybe they still are and I've just been bypassing those quests? But even then those quests only allowed me to collect for one companion. Is there any way to get them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there has never been a way to collect all of the equipment for all of your (1-50) companions.
Now that companions do not require gear at all to function in combat (besides a weapon), it seems that there is no way to get these old alternative outfits for companions specifically besides their default outfit.

Comment: Some companions (most of the human ones at least) can wear armor. It does not provide stats, but it looks as expected.

Comment: @zozo OP is asking for the equipment pieces you use to get from doing quests while leveling, this would always give you the choice between (example) a leg piece for one of your current companions. If you did all quests on a planet, you would usually end up with a whole set for a companion.